# MSTest Named Parameters DataRow

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

It is possible to pass in data to a unit test using the DataRow attribute (in combination with the DataTestMethod attribute). However, I want to know if it is possible to pass in data to named parameters of the unit test.

For example, I would currently have to do:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(1, null, 3)]
public void MyTest(int? first = null, int? second = null, int? third = null)
{
    // Test stuff...
}
```

Whereas, I would like to be able to:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(first: 1, third: 3)]
public void MyTest(int? first = null, int? second = null, int? third = null)
{
    // Test stuff...
}
```

I'm aware that this syntax is not 'feasible', it is more like pseudo code to convey my question.

Comment: No, using named parameters is not an available feature in the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if it is possible to pass in data to named parameters of the unit test.

No, passing named parameters is not an available feature in the current version of MSTest.